# javascript coding - multiple inputs and outputs, and looking up outputs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code the following:

there will be six inputs, say 1,2,3,4,5,6

inputs 2-6 have two possible options (say yes and no)

input 1 has seven possible options (say a-g)

depending on which inputs are selected, a specific output will be generated.

So if you had -  a, yes, yes, no, no, no - it would generate outcome 'x'

I have managed to create a list with all the possible input combinations (using python):

```
list = [[23,24,25,26,27,28,29],["male","female"],["true","false"],["true","false"],["true","false"],["true","false"]]

r=[[]]
for e in list:
    table = []
    for item in e:
            for i in r:
                table.append(i+[item])
    r = table

print r
```

My next stage is to allocate an outcome to each of these options.  I guess the best way to do this is just append the output to each list item so that

for e in index, if e[0]-e[5] matches the input then print out e[6]

Is this an ok way to do it?

**EDIT**

Just to make it clearer I just thought I'd explain what I am actually trying to do. It's a free tool for doctors (I'm a doc - it's not for commercial purposes just to improve patient care).

It is a way of calculating risk for the patient, so there will be five questions the doc will input - e.g. male/female etc and depending on their inputs it will produce the outcome as a % risk for the patient. We are using years of previous patient outcome data to produce the table of outcome.

Comment: So 7*2*2*2*2*2 is 224 possible outcomes.  You're saying you want to hard code all of those into a giant map of some sort?

Comment: Any more context available? Got any code you've tried already (regardless of language)?

Comment: Mike - yes, that's right.  A giant map that I can then look up to match the input.

Comment: Daniel - thanks.  I am at the very beginning and just trying to work out how to approach it.  I'm going to get started with the idea below and see how I get on.  Will post back with my progress

Answer (score 2):

You can think of input 2-6 as 5 bits (5 boolean values), and input 1 as 3 higher bits (to encode 7 values). Then loop from 0 to 223, and generate all the possible combination by decoding the number as the scheme above.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I will get started with this and will post back to let you know how I get on. Much appreciated.